# Is it unsafe to send and receive raw structures through sockets?

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm working on a remoting control program. I need to send and receive multiple data at once. I use this solution:

```
struct PACKET
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

//...
PACKET p;
p.x = 10;
p.y = 5;
send(socket, (char*)&p, sizeof(PACKET), 0);
```

However, I'm considering if this is a safe way to do so. Should I find another solution?

Comment: As you can see in vsoftcos answer, there are alot of pitfalls. If you do not want to worry about them, there is [Google Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf/) that takes care of many things for you. However it adds another compiler step for you to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe, unless you can guarantee at least that your structure is a [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/4178176#4178176), which it is in your case, and that both platforms use the same [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), which you don't know.

**EDIT**

There are some additional issues that may occur: alignment is one (the compiler may pad your structure with additional bits), then the data itself can be represented using different models. Thanks to @Andrew and @Slyps for the comments.

So after all it seems that unless you know exactly your data alignment/representation model/endianness on both platforms, you are not safe.

Comment: Well, you can still know about endianness if you control both endpoints of the connection.

Comment: @GregHewgill yes, that's true, if you write a program for your own remote device. Edited it.

Comment: Not just endianness - data model and compiler specifics, too.  A `long` in an ILP32 data model is different from a `long` in an LP64 data model.  Different compilers and/or optimization options can also change the way a structure is laid out.

Comment: Alignment might also stab you in your back. [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273913(v=vs.60).aspx)/[Link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html)

Comment: @Andrew, Slyps thanks for the comments. I was aware of alignment and forgot to mention. However I did not know that the data itself can be represented differently.

Comment: To clarify this a little, if you can be sure that both ends of the connection are running the exact same executable, then it is safe.